# PHP Line Feeds "\n" Not Saving

Tags: php

For some reason with my code which I'm using \n to break the line, isn't working.

It is outputting without breaking the lines.

```
            $file = "availables.txt";
            $current .= $test."\n";
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

I'm not sure what's wrong but I read that using single quotes (') doesn't work and I have to use double quotes (") which is what I'm using.

I couldn't really find much but I'm sure this is just a simple issue :)

Comment: Have You tried "\r\n"?

Comment: `$test . PHP_EOL;` ... what operating system?

Comment: Using "\r\n" worked! Thankyou so much! Sorry, a bit new to this :)

Comment: @user3807836 It depends on operating system. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: When you say "outputting without linebreaks", where are you viewing the output? If read back out to the browser as HTML, you won't see them without `nl2br()` unless you view the source. If you are reading the text file on Windows, some low-end text editors (Notepad) won't properly handle `\n` linebreaks.

Comment: Alternative is to use some unix-aware editor on Windows. Even WordPad should properly show file using "\n" convention.

Comment: One should tell you that while "\r\n" worked on Windows it may look clumsy under Unix or Mac on the other hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments the issue is in selecting the correct line ending symbol for the platform.

The core constant [`PHP_EOL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) will do this for you allowing you to create portable code.

> > The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform. Available since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2

Answer (score 1):

It's true that a line feed character enclosed in single quotes won't work, that's simply because PHP will insert a backspace `\` followed by an `n` into the file. This results in the ASCII/UTF-8 hex code `0x2F0x6E` instead of simply `0xA`.

Using either `"\n"` or the predefined constant `PHP_EOL` which will always contain the correct line feed combination for your platform will resolve this issue.

There's absolutely nothing wrong with the code you posted in your question. So what's wrong? My guess is the program you use to view the resulting file. Some broken Windows applications won't read the line feed correctly because they expect the file to use Windows line feeds (which is a combination of line feed and carriage return as you might know).

You're using PHP, output the file in your browser (no matter which), they'll handle it correctly. Simply:

```
<?php

header("content-type: text/plain");
echo "hello\nworld";
```

And you'll see that everything is fine.

Answer (score -2):

You can write you variable inside double quotes like this

```
$current .= "$test\n";
```

Comment: Your post does **NOT**  provide an answer!